# индекс несуществующего обьекта django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

Добрый день!

django 1.10 python 3.5 posgresql 9.5

Добавил новый объект Question и он добавился с id=3, вчера добавлял объект но потом его удалил.
Почему новый объект не добавился с id=2.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
question_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date>=timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
choice_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
votes=models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Потому, что идентификаторы - это последовательно нарастающие числа. Когда вы удаляете строку из таблицы, идентификатор не "освобождается".

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL хранит идентификаторы в, так называемых, последовательностях (Sequences). Вы можете посмотреть Sequence через любую ide для работы с базой данных. В Sequence хранится следующий id для назначения при следующем INSERT-е в базу данных. UPDATE-ы и DELETE-ы не влияют на значение в Sequence-е.
Вот [здесь](http://doc.artofweb.ru/doc/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_PostgreSQL), подробнее описано, как это работает